# Force Google sheets to complete cell formulas before app script copies cell data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google sheets App that is time triggered, it is not waiting for all sheet calculations to finish before the scripts grabs the data to record.

The UI shows data in the expected calculated cells.  Some ranges in the same sheet work in my script (fewer/zero external calls perhaps?).

The nonworking cells depend upon google external calls for stock price data, so they take some time.   Show "loading..." instead of the expected numbers

This is new behavior.   Flush and sleep don't seem to help.

```
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
  Utilities.sleep(1000);  // sleep

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range_name = 'history'

  var new_row_data = [ [ 
                        ss.getRangeByName( 'Foo').getDisplayValue(),
                        ss.getRangeByName( 'barTotal').getDisplayValue(),
                        ss.getRangeByName( 'CALC1').getDisplayValue(), 
                        ss.getRangeByName( 'bzzTotal').getDisplayValue() , 
                        ss.getRangeByName( 'CALC2').getDisplayValue() ,
                       ] 
                     ];
```

ASK:  how to get spreadsheet to complete cell execution before my script copies that data.

LOG DATA OUTPUT:

```
Data: [ 573133.51, 17425.454, Loading..., 261529.30, Loading... ]
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that waiting an arbitrarily long time (ie `Utilities.sleep(20000)`) gives you the result you want? If it does, I might recommend a `while` loop, while you keep checking the value of a cell you know has this specific issue. I think `flush` only applies any pending GAS changes, not necessarily any pending formula calculations, so probably not gonna help here.

Comment: Since writing this, I have implemented a while loop to repeatedly test for "loading..." until complete.   That addresses my immediate problem, but it seems unsatisfying that there isn't a simpler, perhaps built in approach to this.

Comment: `while` loops seem to be [the recommendation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132311/how-to-wait-for-google-spreadsheet-calculations-to-update-before-retrieving-cell) even as of a couple years ago. I would say GAS and Google in general will constantly leave you unsatisfied with their implementations.

Comment: Try replacing all of your formula with a script

Answer (score 1):

The following polling code worked for me to wait until the CALC2 range completed it's calculations

```
  var count = 0;
  while ( ss.getRangeByName( 'CALC2').getDisplayValue() == "Loading..." 
          && count < 15 )
  {
     Utilities.sleep(1000);  // sleep
     count++;
  }
  if ( count >= 15 ) {
    Logger.log('Failed to load need data in %s sec', count );
    return;
  }
```